# Get ComboBox selected Layer's path as a string to use in OGR/GDAL method

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qt

I'm making a plugin that converts vector .shp to raster .tif. This is the UI of the plugin. The ComboBox is the custom mMapLayerComboBox widget.

[image: UI of the Plugin]

1. After selecting a loaded shapefile in QGIS, what is the type of the `layer` object that I'll use in the python code as a shapefile? This is the code:

[image]

Also, OSGEO/OGR/GDAL needs a string as an argument (the pathfile of the shapefile to be exact) as input. So `ogr.Open(layer)` gives an error.
This is the error:

[image: Not a String error]

But running `ogr.Open(layer)` in Jupyter, where `layer = 'datasets/input/Agriculture.shp'` gives no error and runs the code properly.

So,
2. How do I get the pathfile of the shapefile from the ComboBox? (if not ComboBox, what other widgets can I use)?

Comment: Could you add the code and the error message as text instead of image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, `layer` is an instance of `QgsVectorLayer`, because `currentLayer` gives you that. But `ogr.Open()` needs a path. So you need to get layer source to pass to `ogr.Open()`. `QgsVectorLayer` class has `source` method which gives you full path of the layer source.

Use in that way:

```
layer = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()
layer_path = layer.source()

dataSource = ogr.Open(layer_path)
ogr_layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but mMapLayerComboBox doesn't have source as a method, an error came when I used. used normal comboBox with which it now works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `QgsMapLayerComboBox` doesn't have `source` method. It's `QgsMapLayer`'s method.  `mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()` returns a `QgsMapLayer` instance (means layer).